# English etymology dictionary usable on Windows

Tags: windows, web-apps, language, dictionary

There's this video where a guy explains meanings of medical terms:

https://youtu.be/TMy0vJfKvzI?t=178

He explains the word "hypokalemia" as:

- "hypo" - meaning "low"
- "kal" - meaning "potassium" (K)
- "emia" - meaning "presence in blood"

I was wondering if there's a site/software that does this for **all words** (in english language, not just medical terms).

OS: Windows

Price limit: $100 (per year in case of a subscription model)

Comment: Dictionaries usually provide some information on a word's etymology, where possible. For example, http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypokalemia#source-word-origin Do you need a desktop software specifically? Is there any particular reason for that, like text editor integration or mass processing?

Answer (score 0):

A start for a DIY piece might be this [dictionary](https://www.learnthat.org/pages/view/roots.html) along with its companion for suffixes.

There are a few Python codes at [Python codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156448/parsing-words-into-prefix-root-suffix-in-python) -- they produce output like:

```
construct
['con', 'struct']
- prefixes: ['con']
- root: struct
['con']
struct
```

So combining the definitions from the first link with something like the codes in the second might help answer your question. It also looks like one would want to add a local dictionary for medical and other professional terms.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

In my experience each dictionary varies in its ability to break the words down, because that's usually not done by an automatic tool but manually by the dictionary's composer.

It's not easy to automate this because some affixes got changed a bit when applying to the roots (most commonly occur when the 2 merging ends are 2 vowels), and sometimes what *looks* like an affix isn't a real affix. For example `-emia` actually contains the suffix `-ia`, but should you split the infix `-em-` as well? In Latin there are a lot of infixes like `-m-`, `-n-`, `-an-`, `-de-`... which are almost impossible for the machine to know where to split

---

As a result it's better to compare the result from various sources

It seems [TheFreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/) *often* does the best work of showing the full etymology. This is what you get for *hypokalemia:*

> [hypo- + New Latin kalium, potassium (from Medieval Latin kali, alkali, potassium, from Arabic qily, ashes, lye, potash; see alkali) + -emia.]
>
> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypokalemia

You can click the `hypo-` and `-emia` links to get more detailed meanings

[Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) also gives the same information for [hypokalemia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypokalemia) but not for many other words

[Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/) is a good source of etymology, too. It's often the one with most detailed information about a word across languages.

Comment: +1 to Wiktionary. The best source of parsed data is https://kaikki.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I simply use Google.  For instance:

```
  sophisticated etymology
```

Google will give you the word origin and detailed analysis.

Comment: They never get macabre right; the word comes from the Arabic "ma cabr" (cemetery).